# Is it advisable to use EPDM for flooring around the pool?

Tags: water, flooring, pool, rubber

I am planning to use EPDM flooring around the pool so that it will provide grip and kids won't get hurt when they fall. But few people said that EPDM does not do well around water. Is there something I am missing. There are few online images that show EPDM around the pool. Can someone suggest

Answer (score 2):

Anyone who says that "EPDM does not do well around water" is ignorant of what the material is. It is used specifically as a water resistant membrane for roofing and many other applications, including around pool decks.

It is not the material itself that is an issue, it is how you intend to use it and how it is applied/installed. Your question doesn't specify exactly what you intend to do, but assuming that you will have a professionally applied EPDM coating, with the surface properly prepared and the material mixed and applied as required by the manufacturer.

Comment: It is for the deck of the pool not inside the pool.

Comment: We did add epdm. It is working well

Answer (score 0):

EPDM is the best material for Water or harsh weather. As I understand you are looking for sponge EPDM Sheets to provide cushioning. This will serve your purpose.

However, you can try "EVA Sheets" which are **comparatively very-very cheap** & can be used for this purpose.